# Reading characters and integers from file in C

Tags: c, input, file-io, io, fread

I am working on a school project - reading lines from a text file that I need separated into bank accounts and balances where:

1. 'a' represents the account
2. 'b' represents bank account followed by balance (integer)
3. 'c' represents client

I have used fread() to scan the contents of the file into a character array however I am attempting to extract the account balance (ints) into another array so that I can process client transactions on those balances. I have managed to extract the number of bank accounts and number of clients performing transactions with my for loops below although i'm not sure how to extract the balance as an integer from the array.

Sample text file: [sample text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1G7o.jpg)

Text File format is always the same however the number of bank accounts and number of clients is always >=1 for any given text file

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

char *path; 
FILE *fp;
char lines[100];
char accounts[100];
pthread_mutex_t lock; //mutex for critical section
path = argv[1]; //file to open
int i = 0;
int numAccounts = 0;


if ( argc != 2 ) {
        printf("No file passed\n");
    exit(0);
}

/* open file for read */
fp = fopen(path,"r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    exit(0); 
}

fread(lines, 1, 100, fp);   
size_t length = sizeof(lines) / sizeof(lines[0]); 
    puts(lines);
int clientcount = 0;
int balances[100];



//pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); 
    
 for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {   
    if (lines[i] == 'b') {
     numAccounts++;         
    }

    if (lines[i] == 'c' ) {
     clientcount++;     
    }

 }


printf("%d\n",clientcount);
printf("%d\n",numAccounts);
printf("%d\n",balances);




fclose(fp);

return(0);
}
```

Comment: `fread` is not the best API to use for this. Because it doesn't help you seperate lines. Instead suggest you use `fgets` which reads one line at a time. Then write seperate functions for parsing accounts and customers. Then based on the first character of a line you can call the appropriate function. Breaking up the problem like this will help you build up the code a bit at a time.

Comment: Also, have you learnt `struct` and data structures? To store the accounts and customers the usual way will be to define one or more data structures to store the parsed data.

Comment: your file does not contain uniform data in every row,how one supposed to know what is `c1 d a1 100 w a2 500 t a1 a2 25`? make the file uniform by listing proper entries.